# Creating a part of the refman document as pdf

Tags: pdf-generation, doxygen

I have a complex piece of software that is documented using Doxygen.

What I need is to create a short part of the HTML document as a sort of user guide to be printed out. Refman is extremely long and includes lots of details that are interesting only for developers. I need only a small portion of it as a PDF file.

I could not find information on how to do this, and I appreciate any hints and useful discussion on how-to's!